# Is ternary working with dynamic attribute in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, attributes, conditional-operator

I try to change the id of a div with angular and i use these code:

```
<div [id]="'item_' + (itemName !== undefined ? itemName.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() : '')">
```

but when i launch my test and i don't define the itemName i have these error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

So, where is my mistake ? is it possible to use ternary here like that, is there any other way to do what i'm trying to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to use a pipe for this - https://angular.io/guide/pipes.

Comment: Use a property on your controller instead of inline script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your expression is interpreted this way :

```
itemName !== ( undefined ? itemName.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() : '' )
```

To fix it, add parenthesis here :

```
(itemName !== undefined) ? itemName.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() : ''
```

Comment: i just did what you said and it doesn't changed anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, so the error probably comes from somewhere else. About the ternary operator, you can simplify this by using the angular template safe navigation operator:

```
<div [id]="'item_' + (itemName?.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() || '')">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Add in .ts file , do the id generation logic in Oninit()

```
itemName? : string;

<div [id]="itemName"></div>
```